# FileLoaderLoadException - can not get LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle to work - Symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I am trying to build my rest api with symfony and https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle
I did everything as described in examples but everytime i set the type of my api to "rest" in my routing.yml i get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                      
Class could not be determined for Controller identified by 
"InveusUserBundle/Controller/UsersController" in 
InveusUserBundle/Controller/UsersController
(which is being imported from "/vagrant/app/config/routing.yml").
Make sure there is a loader supporting the "rest" type.
```

Comment: Did you configure FosRestBundle in your `app/config/config.yml` file ?

Comment: Yes, did all the cofiguration also followed custom tutorials and the offical symfony doc

Answer (score -1):

Add route to your controller in: YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
myconfig:
    type: rest
    prefix: /api
    resource: YourBundle\Controller\Api\YourController
    name_prefix:  api_ # naming collision
```

Imoprt your bundle routing.yml file into app/config/routing.yml

```
appRoute:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    type: rest
    prefix:   /api
```

This config should fix the error.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my cose is already as you say, and not work